# Severe Case of Missing data

Tags: missing-data

I have a dataset with i number of variables.

One of the variables has only 50% available data ( total is about 1500). If I distribute the records into regions (=27) (or stratum), sample size per stratum would be too small.

If I do multiple imputation, will the resulting dataset valid for per stratum analysis? The set of predictors I will use to do the multiple imputation can correctly classify the records about 60% at a time based on a multinomial logistic regression result.

Comment: Why would you want to "distribute" the records into regions/strata and perform separate analysis? If there is a region/strata effect, why not control for it. Also, you mentioned that one of your variables has 50% missingness - does this have anything to do with your decision to divide into regions/strata?

Comment: the client wants to do interpretation in the strata level, thus the need to make the estimates valid at a region/strata level. The 50% missingness is at the country level.